C++ - Why does the cin inside the if statement get skipped over when it is under a while loop reading an unknown number of inputs?
My code skipped over the cin under the while loop reading an unknown number of inputs.
I wanted to run the code
int curval = 0, val = 0;
    while(std::cin >> curval){
        val++;
    }
    if (val == 3){
        std::cin >> val;  //Why does the terminal skip this cin
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }

However, when I input, 4 4 4 and input control D as end of file, the code outputs
3D. (Also why is there a D there)
When I click return the program doesn't end. So it just keeps asking me for inputs for the while loop, and regardless of wether the number of integere=s matches the if statement the second cin never executes.
Why does the code not ask for an input after the condition of 3 values is met. I was expecting that when I inputed 4 4 4 control d, it would ask for another value.
Thank you, and sorry if this is poorly organized this is my first ever question on stack overflow.

Because it's in the fail state until you clear it.

while(std::cin >> curval) only stops when input fails, then the stream is in a fail state and will not read until you reset it

The D is part of the Control-D you pressed. It displays as ^D and then the ^ is replaced with the output 3.

The code broke out of the while loop because std::cin said that there was no more input and the attempted read failed. At std::cin >> val there still is no more input, so the read again fails.

After a read error, the input stream is in FAIL or EOF state. To be able to continue reading, you have to:

reset the stream state to the GOOD condition (std::cin.clear())
read the offending character out of the stream to be able to read further numbers

For example:
if (val == 3){
    char c;
    std::cin.clear();     // reset the error condition
    std::cin >> c;        // skip the offending character
    std::cin >> val;      // and proceed reading
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
}



Why does the code not ask for an input after the condition of 3 values is met.

The condition, if (val == 3), is outside the loop. The actual loop will continue to read values from std::cin until it fails. Be it one or a million values.

I was expecting that when I inputed 4 4 4 control d, it would ask for another value.

Ctrl-D is generally used in unix-like systems to signal end-of-file. When you do that, the eofbit is set on the input stream std::cin and that makes any further attempts to extract anything from the stream fail.
When extraction fails, the failbit is also set on the stream. That is the reason why the while loop is exited; it fails to extract an int:
Any std::istream, like std::cin will return false in a boolean context if fail() returns true. fail() returns true if badbit or failbit is set on the stream.
The only way to make further extractions from the same open stream possible is to clear() the badbit and failbit state bits - and you must then also discard any offending character(s) that is still stored in the stream's buffer. The easiest way to do that is to discard all character up until (and including) the first newline character in the stream:
// #include <limits> required
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

Note though: Even if you successfully clear() the eofbit from std::cin in a unix-like system, the actual shell you use (bash or similar) will most likely close the input stream when you press Ctrl-D, so the next extraction you try will then set the eofbit (and consequently the failbit) again. Don't use Ctrl-D if you intend to enter more values into the program's input stream.
